# Is there a way to switch the a globally defined variables scss file in Nuxt.js using Vuex and Middleware?

Tags: sass, vuex, middleware, nuxt.js

I am trying to find a way to dynamically change which `_variables.scss` file gets loaded globally based on a saved state in my Vuex store in my Nuxt.js universal web application. Is there any possible way to do this outside of the `nuxt.config.js` file?

I am unable to share much of the code do to company policy, but let me set up where I am at.  We have different types of customers trying to access a version of our web app.  Each type logs in on a different domain i.e. Green customers login via `www.green.com/login`, Red customers via `www.red.com/login` and so forth. The theme of the layout, meaning colors, fonts, etc. are determined by which `_variables.scss` gets loaded.

Currently I have middleware `theme.js` in my Nuxt.js app that gets the domain, splits the host (`www.red.com` becomes just `red`) and is saved to the vuex store as `state.theme`.

Now I am unable to figure out how to load `red_variables.scss` or `green_variables.scss` dynamically based on the state.

Comment: Shouldn't you use css variables instead? seems like a perfect use case for that

Answer (score 1):

So after some trial and error a solution was found, not elegant but it works. Created a middleware file called `theme.js` and it looks something like this:

```
  const domain = host.split(':')[0]
  switch (true) {
    case domain.includes('red.com'):
      return {
        theme: 'red'
      }
    case domain.includes('green.com'):
      return {
         theme: 'green'
      }
    /*** more cases for different themes ***/
    default:
      return 'main'
  }
}

function loadTheme(theme) {
  import('~assets/css/' + theme + '.scss')
}

export default function({ app, req, store, error }) {
  let theme = store.state.theme

  if (!theme && process.server) {
    if (req && req.headers && req.headers.host) {
      const themeSettings = mapHostToTheme(req.headers.host)

      theme = themeSettings.theme
      store.commit('setTheme', theme)
    }
  }

  if (!theme) {
    return error({
      statusCode: 500,
      message: 'Unable to determine host'
    })
  }

  loadTheme(theme)
}
```

Essentially grabs the host name, confirms the domain, adds the theme name to the store, then loads the proper `.scss` file based on the name stored in the Vuex state.

Comment: Hi! Where did you load the original _variables?